# how to create sub queries in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

excuse me, I'm still confused by the use of sub queries to be implemented in the following table.

I have 2 tables like the following with relation table id_activity

Table 1 for main table
[image]

Table 2 for detail table 1
[image]

the results I want are as follows
[image]

Note*

1. column date_yesterday, yesterday, interaksi and status are searched from the column today but based on the previous day.
2. column date_today and today are searched by today
3. the inprogress and issue columns are taken from the column that contains the value in that column, if the column has no value then it is not included.

I have tried with queries like this, but not according to what I want

```
SELECT detail_activity.id as id, header_activity.tanggal, detail_activity.today, detail_activity.issue, detail_activity.inprogress, detail_activity.interaksi, detail_activity.status (SELECT tanggal from header_activity left join detail_activity on detail_activity.id_activity = header_activity.id_activity WHERE header_activity.tanggal = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),"%Y-%m-%d") AND header_activity.id_karyawan = '23') as tanggal_kemarin from header_activity left join detail_activity on detail_activity.id_activity = header_activity.id_activity WHERE header_activity.tanggal = CURDATE() AND header_activity.id_karyawan = '23'
```

maybe someone can help me to resolve this case

Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And please format your code